# Can't open my kippo-graph page

Tags: 16.04

I have set up the kippo-graph in my machine but I can't seem to access the page ,the page simply won't load .
Here are some screenshots of what I'm trying to do :

Here are details of my machine 
[image]

The highlighted area is where the kippo-graph is saved 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are not root add `sudo` before.

```
wget http://bruteforcelab.com/wp-content/uploads/kippo-graph-1.5.1.tar.gz
mv kippo-graph-1.5.1.tar.gz /var/www/html
cd /var/www/html
tar -zxvf kippo-graph-1.5.1.tar.gz
mv kippo-graph-1.5.1 kippo-graph
cd kippo-graph
chmod 777 generated-graphs
cp config.php.dist config.php
nano config.php #enter the appropriate values
```

web browser http://localhost/kippo-graph